# How to convert into html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code to pull a phone search data and assign into  target_id:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var ajax_load = "<h2>Please wait</h2>";

        jQuery(target_id).html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl);
```

This is the output from the GET query but it's not correctly showing in the HTML:

### Result from GET

```
({"r": "<div class=\"phone_results\"><div class=\"phoneblock\">\n\t<div class=\"img\"><img src=\"http:\/\/directory.ddnschool.ac.in\/noimage\/NoImageM_xsm.png\"><\/div>\n\t<div class=\"text\">\n\t    <div class=\"name\">Agg,  <\/div>\n\t\n\t\n\tBusiness: 150 IT Office<br \/>\n\t<\/div>\n\t<hr class=\"divider\" \/>\n    <\/div>\n<div class=\"phoneblock\">\n\t<div class=\"img\"><img src=\"http:\/\/directory.ddnschool.ac.in\/noimage\/NoImageM_xsm.png\"><\/div>\n\t<div class=\"text\">\n\t    <div class=\"name\">Gup, Ag<\/div>\n\t<a class=\"email\" href=\"mailto:agg@ddnschool.ac.in\">agg@ddnschool.ac.in<\/a><br \/>\n\tt Lower<br \/>\n\tBusiness: 305 IT Manager's Office<br \/>\n\t<\/div>\n\t<hr class=\"divider\" \/>\n    \n\
\n\
\n\
<\/div>\n<\/div><br style=\"clear: both\" \/><div class=\"message\"> &nbsp; <span>Showing 1 - 2 of 2 results.<\/span> &nbsp; <\/div>"});
```

So this is JSON data and I need to remove backslashes too. What is the best way to show it in HTML?

Comment: your response looks like a jsonp response(because of the surrounding `()` - looks like the callback name is missing)... so you should be passing a jsonp callbak method name also

Comment: do seperate loading and merging html operations;

Comment: the solution should look some thing like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/22W4y/1/) but we need more information... like what is the value of `loadUrl`?

Comment: Is `loadurl` response is in your control?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$.ajax({
    url: loadUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $(target_id).html(data.r);
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68hLE/)